# Retrieve a value from a script and replace a DIV with it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to retrieve from the code below the value of `"city"` which in this case is **Bothell** and use the text to replace a DIV in my HTML. This is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var f = function() {
    realgeeks.analytics.send_activity({
      "site_uuid": "09bce392-c259-4c5b-ba82-02547e30f980",
      "property": {
        "city": "**Bothell**",
        "full_baths": 3,
        "listing_status": "ACTIVE",
        "year_built": 1984,
        "zip": "98012",
        "listing_days_on_market": 3,
        "url": "http://www.bothellhomes.com/property/1265902/",
        "sqft": "1306",
        "tags": ["Snohomish", "Southeast Snohom",
          "Thrashers Corner", "Parkshore", "Bothell",
          "98012", "Parkshore Div 4", "1265902",
          "Northshore"
        ],
        "longitude": -122.204533,
        "beds": 3,
        "mls": "1265902",
        "state": "WA",
        "images": [
          "https://property-media.realgeeks.com/40/8039f526bebf11225fda49555d1f4217.jpg",
          "https://property-media.realgeeks.com/40/cd649b5ae431bec9fe4a5802a6520f5e.jpg",
          "https://property-media.realgeeks.com/40/a43099b8b8b30772b019ac2aaea3460f.jpg"
        ],
        "latitude": 47.830478,
        "listing_price": "440000",
        "type": "Single Family Residential",
        "list_date": "2018-04-01T00:00:00+00:00",
        "street_address": "18430 20th Dr SE"
      },
      "type": "property_viewed"
    });
  };
  f();
  $(document).on('fb-lead-login', f);
});
```

How would I go about doing this, knowing I don't have access to this block of code due to my web provider?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to spoof analytics. If you are, you're going about it the wrong way. And while you can indeed send through a city from your own HTML element, you certainly can't do so without modifying the above code.

Comment: Sure he can. Investigate the use of the Proxy object. Proxy the f() method, get/change, the execute the original f() method. simple.

Comment: I can write a script in the footer of the site on the same page as this code.

Comment: Is there a way to do this with Jquery?

Comment: Why insist on jQuery? [Proxy it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)

Comment: Mainly because I don't understand how this type of code works. Kind of a noob at this. Not sure how to structure the code to proxy it and use that to replace a div on the same page.